# Synpress cannot use cy.acceptMetamaskAccess (is not a function)

Tags: javascript, json, cypress, e2e-testing, metamask

I'm trying to use Synpress, but I fail to understand how to solve

```
TypeError: cy.acceptMetamaskAccess is not a function
```

Let me share the relevant code* (I mostly followed this tutorial https://medium.com/andamp/how-to-setup-synpress-for-wen3-dapp-frontend-test-automation-with-metamask-73396896684a)

*if something is missing, please let me know

### package.json:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^8.0.2",
    "cypress": "^9.7.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "test": "env-cmd -f .env npx synpress run -cf synpress.json --config supportFile='tests/support/index.js'",
    "test:watch": "env-cmd -f .env npx synpress open -cf synpress.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@synthetixio/synpress": "^1.2.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0"
  }
}
```

### How I configured my synpress.json

```
{
    "baseUrl": "https://dappify.com/",
    "userAgent": "synpress",
    "retries": { "runMode": 0, "openMode": 0 },
    "integrationFolder": "tests/integration",
    "screenshotsFolder": "screenshots",
    "videosFolder": "videos",
    "video": true,
    "chromeWebSecurity": true,
    "viewportWidth": 1366,
    "viewportHeight": 850,
    "component": {
      "componentFolder": ".",
      "testFiles": "**/*spec.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    },
    "env": {
      "coverage": false
    },
    "defaultCommandTimeout": 30000,
    "pageLoadTimeout": 30000,
    "requestTimeout": 30000,
    "supportFile": "tests/support/index.js"
  }
```

### Simple test

```
describe('Test User Login', () => {

    
    it('Connects with Metamask', () => {
        cy.visit('https://dappify.com')
        cy.contains('Sign').click(); 
        cy.contains('Confirm').click();
        cy.contains('Connect Wallet').click();
        cy.contains('Metamask').click();
        cy.switchToMetamaskWindow();
        cy.acceptMetamaskAccess().should("be.true");

    })
  })
```

I don't understand why `cy.acceptMetamaskAccess()` is not a function, I can find it here: https://github.com/synthetixio/synpress/blob/master/support/index.d.ts

How can I use the functions listed in this `index.d.ts` file?

### ** Solution **

Answer by Fody was helpful! Let me summarise the steps needed:

- inside `support` folder you need an `index.js`

inside `index.js`

```
import './commands'
import "@synthetixio/synpress/support";
```

If you want to add custom functions add this file to `support` too

inside `commands.js`:

```
import "@testing-library/cypress/add-commands";

// here go(es) your custom function(s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit hard to untangle the Synpress structure. Usually with a plugin library you import a support component and that adds the library's custom commands to your test.

The article says

> Run your tests with env-cmd -f .env npx synpress run -cf synpress.json **--config supportFile='support/index.js'**

which makes me think the last parameter is bringing in the custom commands.

If you already tried that, the following is the command definition, you can try adding it at the top of your spec.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('acceptMetamaskAccess', allAccounts => {
  return cy.task('acceptMetamaskAccess', allAccounts);
})
```

Comment: while your answer pushed me on the right track, I fail to understand this sentence > "Usually with a plugin library you import a support component and that adds the library's custom commands to your test."

Comment: adding the `Cypress.Commands.add(...)` at the top of my spec didn't work btw.

Comment: I was thinking of, for example, `@cypress/code-coverage` where part od the setup is `import '@cypress/code-coverage/support'`. That adds commands provided in the package to your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Give set parameter in command

```
cy.acceptMetamaskAccess().should("be.true");
```

Example:

```
cy.acceptMetamaskAccess(2).should("be.true");
```

This worked for me.